# Update on SQL Server using AVG and MAX

Tags: sql-server, max, average

Can anyone help me?

I have two tables `Results` and `Students` are shown here:

```
StudentID   CourseID   Year     Semester    Mark 
------------------------------------------------
   S001       DS01     2017        1        3 
   S001       DS01     2017        2        6   
   S001       AI01     2017        1        4.5 
   S001       AI01     2017        2        6 
   S001       CN01     2017        3        5 
   S002       DS01     2016        1        4.5 
   S002       DS01     2017        1        7 
   S002       CN01     2016        3       10 
   S002       DSA1     2016        3        9
```

---

```
StudentID   LastName    FirstName   Sex     DateOfBirth     PlaceOfBirth    DeptID  Scholarship     AverageScore
S001    Lê  Kim Lan     F   23/02/1990  Hà nội  IS  130000  
S002    Trần Minh Chánh     M   24/12/1992  Bình Định   NC  150000
```

(AverageScore now is null)

I want to update with course ID - can you help me please?

This my code:

```
update Students
set AverageScore = (select avg(max(Mark).CourseID) 
                    from Results 
                    where Results.StudentID = Students.StudentID)
```

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. As we can see, you have different courses for the same student and multiple marks for the same course. But you only have one average field in the Student table. Do you want to take the max of each for course for a particular student and avg them and save it in Student table? Ex: 5001 => (6 (max of DS01) + 6 (max of AI01) + 5 (CN01)) / 3 = 17/3 = 5.67

Answer (score 0):

You can use following sub query:

```
update Students set AverageScore = (select avg(marks) from (
     Select max(mark) as marks
     from Results 
     where Results.StudentID = Students.StudentID  group by Results.courseid  ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

**you  can try this:**

```
;WITH aa AS(
 SELECT resultid,CourseID,MAX(Mark) mark FROM result GROUP BY resultid,CourseID )
UPDATE dbo.student SET AverageScore=(select AVG(mark) from aa WHERE aa.resultID=student.resultID)
select * from dbo.student
```